# in Vue.js, conditionally display tags if a condition is met without repeating code

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements, dry

First of all, I'm very new to Vue so, sorry if the answer is very obvious. I have a list of elements that I'm rendering with Vue.js, some of these items have a "Sold" attribute and when they have it, the layout has to change a bit, so far this works well:

```
<template v-if="property.sold === 'sold'">
    <span class="property-item-sold">{{ property.sold }}</span>
    <div class="item-meta">
        <h3 class="property-item-title">{{ property.name }}</h3>
        <div class="item-meta-group">
            <div class="location"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> {{ property.location | cityState }} {{ property['property-state'][0].name }}</div>
            <div class="size">{{ property.surface.value | numberFormat }} {{ property.surface.unit }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template v-else>
    <div class="property-item-offering-type">For {{ property['offering-type'][0].name }} </div>
    <div class="item-meta">
        <h3 class="property-item-title">{{ property.name }}</h3>
        <div class="item-meta-group">
            <div class="location"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> {{ property.location | cityState }} {{ property['property-state'][0].name }}</div>
            <div class="size">{{ property.surface.value | numberFormat }} {{ property.surface.unit }}</div>
        </div>
        <a :href="property.url" class="btn btn--green">View Details</a>
    </div>
</template>
```

But I'm repeating a lot of code, is there a way to DRY this conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<template>
    <span v-if="property.sold === 'sold'" class="property-item-sold">{{ property.sold }}</span>
    <div v-else class="property-item-offering-type">For {{ property['offering-type'][0].name }} </div>
    <div class="item-meta">
        <h3 class="property-item-title">{{ property.name }}</h3>
        <div class="item-meta-group">
            <div class="location"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> {{ property.location | cityState }} {{ property['property-state'][0].name }}</div>
            <div class="size">{{ property.surface.value | numberFormat }} {{ property.surface.unit }}</div>
        </div>
        <a v-if="property.sold !== 'sold'" :href="property.url" class="btn btn--green">View Details</a>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! Accepting the answer when it allows me.